# Can't output to QTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qtextedit

My program should:

1. collect some input from QLineEdits;
2. convert it into QStrings;
3. add it to some QStrings which are constant;
4. output the whole stuff in a QTextEdit when a button is clicked.

Below is the simplified model of the program. It can be compiled; I get no errors; however, it doesn't do what I need. It just fails to output and I have really no idea why. I've struggled too hard to get it show no errors and now I've run out of ideas. Can anybody help me please?

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtCore>

class MyObject : public QObject

{
   Q_OBJECT

   public:
   QTextEdit text;
   QString c;

   public slots:
   void onClicked() {
      text.setText(c);
  }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  QWidget mw;
  mw.setWindowTitle("Main Window");
  mw.resize(400, 400);
  mw.show();

    QLabel label ("Enter something:", &mw);
    label.setAlignment(Qt::AlignHCenter);
    label.show();

    QLineEdit line (&mw);
    line.show();

    QString a = line.text();

    QString b = "This line is to be added";

    QString c = a+b;

    QTextEdit text (&mw);
    text.show();

    QPushButton btn ("Convert", &mw);

    MyObject obj;

    QObject::connect(
      &btn,
      SIGNAL(clicked()),
      &obj,
      SLOT(onClicked()));
    btn.show();

  QVBoxLayout layout_mw;

  layout_mw.addWidget(&label);
  layout_mw.addWidget(&line);
  layout_mw.addWidget(&btn);
  layout_mw.addWidget(&text);

  mw.setLayout(&layout_mw);

  return app.exec();

}

#include "sample.moc"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the code you provide it seems that you do not know that:

- Qt works **asynchronously**, for example the value of `a` that you get is before the window is displayed, what value will it have? Well, it will have an empty string, so at what moment should I ask for the text? right in the slot that is called when the button is pressed.
- Variables with the same name do not imply that they are the same, for example you have 2 QTextEdit with the name of text, these are different objects.

So as you realize the objects (widgets) must have the same scope to be able to interact with each other, so I will create a class that inherits from QWidget and that has the other elements as attributes.

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtCore>

class Widget: public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent=nullptr):
        QWidget(parent)
    {
        QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
        layout->addWidget(&label);
        layout->addWidget(&line);
        layout->addWidget(&button);
        layout->addWidget(&textedit);
        label.setText("Enter something:");
        label.setAlignment(Qt::AlignHCenter);
        button.setText("Convert");
        connect(&button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(onClicked()));
    }
private slots:
    void onClicked(){
        QString a = line.text();
        QString b = "This line is to be added";
        QString c = a+b;
        textedit.setText(c); // or textedit.append(c);
    }
private:
    QLabel label;
    QLineEdit line;
    QPushButton button;
    QTextEdit textedit;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();
    return app.exec();
}
#include "sample.moc"
```

Comment: thanks! that was a really helpful answer. it naturally works and I will study everything you said quite thoroughly. thank you :)

Comment: @val To work with Qt you have to have a strong knowledge of OOP so I recommend you review those concepts. On the other hand one of the most important parts of Qt are the signals so I recommend you check the following link: https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html Finally Qt4 is deprecated (I only use it to maintain some projects) so it is recommended that you use Qt5 better since it has many more interesting things

Comment: I agree with your point and you are right, I'm just at the introductory level concerning OOP :) I was just willing to accomplish this project and I also believe in "learning-by-doing" stuff, so I'm really happy you've helped me with that and the next thing I'm going to do after rewriting my code is to study everything (well I will study a large part _while_ rewriting)... :)